# Marionette CompositeView behavior

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

I'm trying to follow a Backbone Rails tutorial and I'm getting stuck trying to render my collection of links in a CompositeView, no nesting involved. I suspect that tutorial is drastically outdated, but since I yet lack Backbone skills I can't pin point the problem. Please, take a look at the following code:

Creating a collection of navigational links.

```
@TestApp.module "Entities", (Entities, App, Backbone, Marionette, $, _) ->

class Entities.Navigation extends Backbone.Model

class Entities.NavigationCollection extends Backbone.Collection
    model: Entities.Navigation

API = 
    getLinks: ->
        new Entities.NavigationCollection [
            { name: "one"   }
            { name: "two"   }
            { name: "three" }
            { name: "four"  }
            { name: "five"  }
        ]

App.reqres.setHandler "navigation:entities", ->
    API.getLinks()
```

Core navigation file.

```
@TestApp.module "NavigationUnit", (NavigationUnit, App, Backbone, Marionette, $, _) ->
@startWithParent = false

API =
    listNavigation: ->
        NavigationUnit.List.Controller.listNavigation()

NavigationUnit.on "start", ->
    API.listNavigation()
```

Controller, where I'm passing collection to the view.

```
@TestApp.module "NavigationUnit.List", (List, App, Backbone, Marionette, $, _) ->

List.Controller =

    listNavigation: ->
        links = App.request "navigation:entities"

        navigationView = @getNavigationView links
        App.navRegion.show navigationView

    getNavigationView: (links) ->
        new List.Navigation
            collection: links
```

And the view.

```
@TestApp.module "NavigationUnit.List", (List, App, Backbone, Marionette, $, _) ->

class List.NavigationLinks extends Marionette.ItemView
    template: "navigation/list/templates/_links"
    tagName: "li"

class List.Navigation extends Marionette.CompositeView
    template: "navigation/list/templates/list_navigation"
    itemView: List.NavigationLinks
    itemViewContainer: "ul"
```

Content of the ItemView template is `%a{:href => "#"}= @name`. And in the CompositeView is a basic wrapper structure with the `%ul` tag. Now what happens is that the CompositeView renders the template as expected, but it does not populate the `%ul` with the itemView. Instead it creates amount of divs equals to the amount of models in the collection (five in this case) and inserts there entire wrapper templates, so it looks like this:

```
#navRegion
  .div
    .navigation-wrapper
      .navigation-content
         %ul
     .div
        .navigation-wrapper
          // entire template
     .div
        .navigation-wrapper
          // entire template
//etc +3 divs
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What is the problem? Errors thrown? It doesn't render?

Comment: The problem is that my ItemView is ignored and instead #navRegion is populated with copies of CompositeView template as if they were a models. Here how it looks like http://i.imgur.com/dLWJEPp.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your tutorial is probably out of date. Marionette renamed the property from `itemView` to `childView` in version 2.0.0.

From [the docs](http://marionettejs.com/docs/v2.4.2/marionette.compositeview.html#compositeviews-childview)

> Each childView will be rendered using the childView's template. The CompositeView's
>   template is rendered and the childView's templates are added to this.

```
var ChildView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({});

var CompView = Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
  childView: ChildView
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, unfortunately when I change `itemView` and `itemViewContainer` to a `childView` and `childViewContainer` respectively, my template error handler throws an error that my `ItemView` does no longer exist. I haven't found anything related to a different templating approach in docs, do I miss something?